# Elasticsearch: return unique records across multiple indexes

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I am trying to return unique records across multiple indexes.

Suppose I have two indexes, indexA and indexB. My elasticsearch queries both of theses indexes.

If I am filtering by the fieldname "Type" (this is in both indexes), how would I only get the unique ones?

Example: indexA has a record with column "type" with value "alpha" and indexB has a record with column "type" with value "alpha". My elastic search query should only output one of these records (does not mater which).

So far I have this:

```
searchParams = {
                "body": {
                    "size": searchService.PAGE_SIZE,
                    "from": searchService.currentPage * searchService.PAGE_SIZE,
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": must
                        }
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "unique_type": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "type",
                                "size": 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

But it's not working.

Thanks!

Comment: May you please add a couple of example documents and expected output of the query? This will help to come up with the query.

Comment: Hi @NikolayVasiliev, 
Lets say first collection has record:
{"name": "paul", "flag": "valid", "type":"A"}
and second collection has record:
{"name":"steve", "flag":"invalid", "type":"A"}

The elastic search query would query both of these collections (indexes) and if i want all unique type of "A", it would only return one of these records (does not matter which).

Thanks!

Comment: Ok I think I know how to help you, please check out the answer I posted, and don't forget to accept and upvote if you find it useful! Please tell me if you have problems with queries, sorry I didn't provide the code to copy&paste, today is just not my day.

Comment: Thanks @NikolayVasilievm hope your week is going better

Answer (score 1):

Your query just needs a little tweak: change the `size` parameter's value.

### How can I return N most frequent values of keyword type across several indexes?

You can use `terms` aggregation to do that. 
In `terms` aggregation the [`size`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-size) parameter limits the amount of buckets your return. In your case you have set it to 1, and this aggregation will return only 1 bucket.

Set size to 10 or other appropriate amount. This will return N most frequent values of that field (`type` in your case).

By the way, all Elasticsearch searches can be done [across multiple indexes simultaneously](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-search.html#search-search-api-path-params).

### What if I also want an example document per each bucket?

[Bucket aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-aggregations-bucket.html) will collect unique values of given kind, called buckets, and count how many documents are in the bucket.

[Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-aggregations.html) return some statistics, like `AVG()` and `SUM()` do in SQL, on the entire result set. They are single numbers, not documents. In your case, Elasticsearch will first restrict the set of documents to those only matching your `must` query that you specified, and then compute all aggregations for that set of documents.

Is there a way to ask Elasticsearch to go back from these aggregation results and fetch a "top hit" for each bucket? There is, and it is called [`top_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation. In your case such `top_hits` aggregation will go inside the `terms` one.

Both `terms` and `top_hits` aggregations have their limitations, like, they cannot return all the buckets if they are too many, or all matching documents, since Elasticsearch tries to be as fast as possible. Please check the corresponding documentation pages.

### What if I do need the entire list of all unique values of a field?

In this case you can use [composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) and paginate over buckets, like you are already doing pagination over search results (with `size` and `from`).

---

Hope this helps!